# How to add multiple wifi connection in my pc while the OS is Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Suppose I got many Wifi Internet connections available for my PC.
But I can only add one connection by clicking one of the available icons of wifi connections.
Now how could I add more connections in any way? Could I do it, or couldn't?
Actually I want to get more download speed through the process.

Comment: You can't have more then one connection at a given time.

Comment: Why? Does it matter with hardwire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding additional hard-wired or wireless connections, to try and increase download speed, is not possible in Ubuntu (although with the proper software, it can be done in Windows).

You CAN have a wired connection, and a wireless connection, at the same time, however download speed won't improve, and Ubuntu will only automatically use the wired connection when it sees both.

To assure maximum wireless download speed, make sure that you have a WPA2-AES connection.

Cheers, Al